# Is there anyway of finding combinations bounded to particular binary numbers?

Tags: arrays, binary

Lets say we have an array of 4 binary numbers i.e [1,0,0,0].

So, this means we do have 4 unique combinations using the formula, (m+n)! / (m! * n!),

Where m is the total number of 1's in that array and n is the total number of 0's in that array.

Now, How can we generate the four unique combinations ?

[ PS: considering dynamic input array containing only 1's and 0's ]

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

Started from here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

I added a little piece of code to avoid duplicates.

```
func permute<T :  Comparable>(a: inout [T], l: Int, r: Int, permutations: inout [[T]])
{
    // Base case
    if l == r
    {
        if !permutations.contains(a)
        {
            permutations.append(a)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Permutations made
        for i in l...r
        {
            // Swapping done
            a.swapAt(l, i)
     
            // Recursion called
            permute(a: &a, l: l+1, r: r, permutations: &permutations)
     
            //backtrack
            a.swapAt(l, i)
        }
     }
}

var array = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
var permutations = [[Int]]()
permute(a: &array, l: 0, r: array.count - 1, permutations: &permutations)
permutations.forEach { (permutazio) in
    print(permutazio)
}
```